# Query/Reports in Excel only

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm trying to use Excel in a way probably more suited for Access. Unfortunately I have no access to Access or Visual Studio (outside the VB prompts in excel.)

I have an excel "database" with several columns (Cust ID, Order Date, Emp ID, Item, etc.) and am looking for ways to be able to run reports in date ranges. For example, total orders from 2/1/15 to 4/1/15 in the Order Date col. Or any order with the Item of XYZ.

I know that pivot tables can help filter data which could take care of the order piece in theory, but I'm not sure how to run reports for items between two dates.

Every article I've found thus far has included Access or Visual Studio. Is there another solution or article anyone could direct me to that uses only Excel? (Until then I'll look for a way to get my hands on Access, but that's on the budget guys to come up with.)

Comment: What do you mean report? Why can't filters or pivot table do the job?

Comment: It was my understanding pivot tables cannot select data in a range. Could I use a pivot to select eveything from "Feb to April" for example?

Comment: You can filter the pivot table.

Comment: Perhaps I'm making things more complicated than they need to be. I'll look more into filtering the pivot tables. Thank you.